# AS3 What happens if you don't extend Object?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, object

In ActionScript 3, when I create a class I generally extend `Object`:

```
public class MyClass extends Object
```

But lately I've just been skipping over that part, and doing:

```
public class MyClass
```

Is there a difference if I don't specifically extend `Object`, or is this already invoked by default?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both class declaration are essentially same. Object is default parent class. Only basic data-types (int, etc) aren't Object.